# How to validate @RequestBody without getters?

Tags: java, spring, validation

Is it possible to tell `spring-web` to automatically validate fields that don't have any getter or setter?

Example:

```
public class PersonForm {
    @NotBlank
    private String date;

    @NotBlank
    private String time;

    //no getter for date or time

    public String getDateTime() {
        return date + "T" + time;
    }

    @Min(0)
    private int age;

    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

The call to `localhost:8080?date=2017-10-10&time=&age=-12` would trigger the `age` property validation as it has a getter. But `time` not having a getter will not be validated.

Can I tell spring to do so and use some kind of *Visibility.FIELD*?

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/foo")
    public void processFoo(@Valid @RequestBody PersonForm form) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: is there specific reason of not having getter for name?

Comment: For example if the user could input several parameters for that I create a "combined" getter that serves only a combination of those values. Eg the user could input `date` and `time` separately, but my Form should only have a `getDateTime()` getter as combination of those. I added this as in the example above

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? I can provide you with a kind of hackish implementation I made of a constraint to check if a specific field has a related getter or not. By now I haven't figured out how to bypass remaining constraints. Nevertheless, I could post it, if you want.

Comment: I did not solve it yet, don't know if it is possible at all...